# What to deal with time-dependent variables in cox proportional hazard model in r

Tags: r, survival-analysis, hazard

I have a question about the time-dependent variables in cox model. Supposed that I have three phases and the event may happen in any time and how can I fit these three time-dependent variables, tr1, tr2, tr3, in cox model? The sample dataset is shown below:

```
tr1 <- c(11.6, 19.04, NA, NA, 10.39, 4.63)
tr2 <- c(63.85, 20.29, NA, NA, 11.64, 7.33)
tr3 <- c(66.51, 22.95, NA, NA, 16.05, 9.11)


if_event <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
sur_time <- c(125.81, 30.23, 59.27, 161.17, 51.36, 7.52)
income <- c(103844, 57246, 83056, 38380, 37518, 900)
population <- c(10000, 20000, 40000, 88000, 90000, 102034)
dat <- cbind(tr1, tr2, tr3, if_event, sur_time, income, population)
```

Can I use **coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ tr1 * tr2 + tr1 * tr3 + tr2 * tr3, data)** to show that time-dependent variables, tr1, tr2 and tr3?

Thanks so much for your kind help.

[image]

More details about the dataset:

tr1, tr2 and tr3 are three time-dependent variables since they have the same starting point, that is, tr1 means the time is from 0 to tr1 time, tr2 means the time from 0 to tr2, tr3 means the time from 0 to tr3. When if_event is 1, it shows that the event has happened and look at the record 1, the survival happened after tr3 time; for record 6, the survival happened between tr2 and tr3.

Comment: The sample data you've posted does not have any time-dependent variables. The structure of your `coxph()` call is also not appropriate for time-dependent variables. So, it's hard to understand what you're asking. Perhaps you should read the time-dependent vignette, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf, then edit your question to clarify. Eg, the data needs to be in "Start, Stop" format. See also the `tmerge()` documentation.

Comment: Hello David. Thanks for your help and reference. I've changed my sample data. Do I need to define during what time span the event happened at first? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still don't see any time-dependent variable in the data. I see 5 different observations, each with constant covariates tr1, tr2, and tr3. Are you intending this to be 5 different time periods for 1 observation?

Comment: Hello David. I've updated more details about the dataset and thanks very much for your kind help.

Comment: I think I understand a little better, but it's still not clear. Do you mean that for individual 1, they were in phase 1 from time 0-11.6, then in phase 2 from 11.6-63.85, then in phase 3 from 66.51-the end? And then the individual experienced a single event at time 125.81, while they were in phase 3? If so, what do you mean by the time-dependent variables "have the same starting point"?

Comment: Hello, something is still a little bit different here. For observation 1, tr1 is from 0 to 11.6, tr2 is from 0 to 63.85, and tr3 is from 0-66.51. The three phases are consecutive and thus we think they are time-dependent variables. Just like the schedule of three meals for a person, phase 1 means the time of breakfast, phase 2 means the time of lunch and phase 3 means the time of dinner. When the survival time is larger than tr_3, then the event is 0, which is the censor data without observations. Do I make it clearly now?

Comment: Not quite... "consecutive" means that the phases happen one after another. So phase 1 would have to end before phase 2 starts. That's why I'm confused about phase 2 starting at time 0. Do you mean "concurrent" instead? Eg, at time 10 individual 1 is in phase 1 and also in phase 2 and also in phase 3?

Comment: Not yet. It means that when tr2 has happened, tr1 has ended and so on. So we would like to say the three time is consecutive. Under our context, tr1 is the time when the return label is created, tr2 is the time when the customer dropped off the return product at the shipper and tr3 is the time when the retailing has received the item. Does it work out now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand you, but I need more space to write.

I think what you mean, is that there are 4 phases. Every individual starts in phase 1, then at time tr1 they move to phase 2, at time tr2 they move to phase 3, and at time tr3 they move to phase 4. Below I create that dataset in start-stop format, as described here. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

```r
library(survival)
dat0 <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  time = c(125.81, 30.23, 59.27, 161.17, 51.36, 7.52),
  status = c(1,1,0,0,1,1))
dat1 <- data.frame(
  id = 1:6,
  time = rep(0, 6),
  phase = factor(c("phase1", "phase1", NA, NA, "phase1", "phase1")))
dat2 <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:6),
  time = c(11.6, 19.04, NA, NA, 10.39, 4.63),
  phase = factor(rep("phase2", 6)))
dat3 <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:6),
  time = c(63.85, 20.29, NA, NA, 11.64, 7.33),
  phase = rep("phase3", 6))
dat4 <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:6),
  time = c(66.51, 22.95, NA, NA, 16.05, 9.11),
  phase = rep("phase4", 6))
dat_rbind <- rbind(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4)
newdat <- tmerge(dat0, dat0, id = id, status = event(time, status))
newdat$time <- NULL
dat <- tmerge(newdat, dat_rbind, id = id, phase = tdc(time, phase))
dat
#>    id status tstart  tstop  phase
#> 1   1      0   0.00  11.60 phase1
#> 2   1      0  11.60  63.85 phase2
#> 3   1      0  63.85  66.51 phase3
#> 4   1      1  66.51 125.81 phase4
#> 5   2      0   0.00  19.04 phase1
#> 6   2      0  19.04  20.29 phase2
#> 7   2      0  20.29  22.95 phase3
#> 8   2      1  22.95  30.23 phase4
#> 9   3      0   0.00  59.27   <NA>
#> 10  4      0   0.00 161.17   <NA>
#> 11  5      0   0.00  10.39 phase1
#> 12  5      0  10.39  11.64 phase2
#> 13  5      0  11.64  16.05 phase3
#> 14  5      1  16.05  51.36 phase4
#> 15  6      0   0.00   4.63 phase1
#> 16  6      0   4.63   7.33 phase2
#> 17  6      1   7.33   7.52 phase3
```

To interpret the data, individual 1 starts in phase 1 at time 0. For 0-11.60 they are in phase 1. At tr1 they have not yet had an event and they move from phase 1 into the next, into phase 2 from 11.60-63.85. Still no event as they move into phase 3 and phase 4. Then at time 125.81 they have an event while they were in phase 4.

For individual 6, they experience an event at time 7.52, while they were in phase 3. This stops any future observations from happening for them, so individual 6 never enters phase 4.

This is like I said in an earlier comment, and you said it wasn't quite right. Can you describe what the problem with this is?

Comment: Hello David. It really helps me out and thanks a lot